# How to search label tag property in c#?

Tags: c#, properties, tags, label

There are 6 labels on the form. TAG property is set to a number between 1 and 6. If I click on 1 label, it generates a random number between 1 and 6. How do I find the label property of a generated number?
firstlbl property = 1, secondlbl property = 2, etc ... Clicking firstlbl generates a number, such as 2. How can I find the label that has tag property 2?
Here is the code:

```
    private void AnyukaLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SikeresTalalat++;
        TalalatiSzamLbl.Text = SikeresTalalat.ToString();
        Random RandomSzam = new Random();
        int KoviSzam = RandomSzam.Next(1, 6);
        MessageBox.Show(KoviSzam.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: You already have an answer how to find the label. A side note: with `RandomSzam.Next(1, 6)` you will get integer numbers from 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

In one line you can do it this way:

```
var label = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Single( x => x.Tag == tag );
```

However, if you're going to be doing this over and over, I suggest you store them in a dictionary for efficiency:

```
var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToDictionary( x => x.Tag, x => x );
```

Then you can find the label in the dictionary with its tag:

```
var label = labels[tag];
```